# Array looping order issue

Tags: asp.net, arrays, arraylist, associative-array, stringbuilder

Hey all i am trying to get my array in the correct format to be placed into an ASP.net webpage for a table for an order.

The order should be:

```
model_number
comm_category
service
freight
sales_tax
sales
unit_price
price
id_price
```

Currently it is outputting as this:

```
model_number
price
unit_price
id_price
sales_tax
sales
service
freight
comm_category
```

And because of this i am unable to append to my string in the correct order using my code here:

```
Public Sub AssocArray_To_String(ByRef Output As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal AssocArrayInput As AssocArray)
    For iParent As Integer = 0 To AssocArrayInput.Count - 1
        Dim intX As Integer = 0
        Dim arrParent As AssocArray = TryCast(AssocArrayInput.Item(iParent), AssocArray)
        If arrParent Is Nothing Then Continue For

        For iChild As Integer = 0 To arrParent.Count - 1
            Call buildItems(PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Keys(iChild)), PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values(iChild)), intX)
            intX += 1
        Next iChild
    Next iParent
End Sub

Private Sub buildItems(ByVal nameOfItem As String, ByVal itemItself As String, ByVal intX As Integer)
    Dim tmpStuff As Decimal = 0.0
    Dim qty As Integer = 1
    Dim model_number As String = ""
    Dim comm_category As String = ""
    Dim service As Double = 0
    Dim freight As Double = 0
    Dim sales_tax As Double = 0
    Dim sales As Double = 0
    Dim unit_price As Double = 0
    Dim price As Double = 0
    Dim id_price As Double = 0

    If nameOfItem = "model_number" Then
        model_number = itemItself
        tableLoop += "<tr><td bgcolor=""#CCCCCC""><asp:Label ID=""item_count_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & qty & "</asp:Label></td>"
        tableLoop += "<td bgcolor=""#CCCCCC""><asp:Label ID=""model_number_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & model_number & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "comm_category" Then
        comm_category = itemItself
        tableLoop += "<td bgcolor=""#CCCCCC""><asp:Label ID=""comm_category_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & comm_category & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "service" Then
        service = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td bgcolor=""#CCCCCC""><asp:Label ID=""service_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & service & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "freight" Then
        freight = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td><asp:Label ID=""freight_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & freight & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "sales_tax" Then
        sales_tax = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td><asp:Label ID=""sales_tax_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & sales_tax & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "sales" Then
        sales = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td bgcolor=""#CCCCCC""><asp:Label ID=""sales_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & sales & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "unit_price" Then
        unit_price = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td bgcolor=""#CCCCCC""><asp:Label ID=""unit_price_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & unit_price & "</asp:Label></td></tr>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "price" Then
        price = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td><asp:Label ID=""amount_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & price & "</asp:Label></td>"
    ElseIf nameOfItem = "id_price" Then
        id_price = Format(Convert.ToDouble(itemItself), "$######.00")
        tableLoop += "<td><asp:Label ID=""id_price_" & intX & """ Text=""Label"">" & id_price & "</asp:Label></td>"
    End If
End Sub
```

The end results are this:

```
<tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="item_count_0" Text="Label">1</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="model_number_0" Text="Label">TTN491-7BW</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="sales_1" Text="Label">3084.63</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="amount_2" Text="Label">3810</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="sales_tax_3" Text="Label">290.37</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="id_price_4" Text="Label">3810</asp:Label></td></tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="comm_category_5" Text="Label">X24</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="service_6" Text="Label">51</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="freight_7" Text="Label">384</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="unit_price_8" Text="Label">3135.63</asp:Label></td></tr>
```

Which should output like this:

```
<tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="item_count_0" Text="Label">1</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="model_number_0" Text="Label">TTN491-7BW</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="comm_category_5" Text="Label">X24</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="service_6" Text="Label">51</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="freight_7" Text="Label">384</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="sales_tax_3" Text="Label">290.37</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="sales_1" Text="Label">3084.63</asp:Label></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><asp:Label ID="unit_price_8" Text="Label">3135.63</asp:Label></td></tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="amount_2" Text="Label">3810</asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="id_price_4" Text="Label">3810</asp:Label></td></tr>
```

How can i put the array in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you just simply referencing the items you need directly, instead of looping through the associative keys (which come back in arbitrary order):

```
Dim arrParent As AssocArray = TryCast(AssocArrayInput.Item(iParent), AssocArray)
If arrParent Is Nothing Then Continue For

Call buildItems("model_number", PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values("model_number")), intX)
Call buildItems("comm_category", PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values("model_number")), intX)
Call buildItems("service", PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values("model_number")), intX)
Call buildItems("freight", PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values("model_number")), intX)
'ETC
```

Or better yet, just get rid of `BuildItems` altogether and inline the logic in the appropriate places above.

Comment: This loops a couple of times (there may be 4 different items in the list) for the array so i take it that it would still work?

Comment: Do all the keys exist in all the array rows, or do some items not have all the keys, for example `freight` doesn't apply to some entries?  If so, there may be a little more work required here.

Comment: They are all the same - it just can have more than 1 item per array. As in model_number, etc etc.. then it starts array 1 model_number, etc etc.. then array 2 model_number, etc etc..

Comment: I get the error **converting from string "model_number" to type "integer" is not valid**?

Comment: What is an `AssocArray` anyway?  And what is `PHPConvert`?  I don't recognize these types so I'm sort of guessing a few things, such as being able to call `arrParent.Values("string")` to lookup a property by name rather than by index.  Since I don't have your code environment and your referenced libraries, you will have to figure that part out.  I've just provided you a rough method/algorithm to solve your problem, not the 100% final tested ready-to-go code.

Comment: AssocArray is a function within a DLL called PHPRPC that converts PHP Serialize to Unserialize > http://phprpc.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
For iChild As Integer = 0 To arrParent.Count - 1
        Call buildItems(PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Keys(iChild)), 
                        PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values(iChild)),  
                        intX)
        intX += 1
Next iChild
```

Therefor you will always get the order of the items in arrParent. So all you have to do ist call buildItems(...) manually in the correct order

```
Call buildItems(PHPConvert.ToString("model_number"), 
                PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values("model_number")),  
                        intX)
Call buildItems(PHPConvert.ToString("comm_category"), 
                PHPConvert.ToString(arrParent.Values("comm_category")),  
                        intX)

' and so on
```

Furthermore I can't find a definition for `tableLoop`  in buildItems. It seems that this is a **simple string variable**. You should make use of a **StringBuilder** as this class is way faster in concatenating strings! See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: I get the error **converting from string "model_number" to type "integer" is not valid**?

Comment: what type is assocArray? can't find any definition. Sorry I assumed that it is possible to access items within this array by name! in case you know the index number of any property you may replace it. e.g if "comm_category" has index number 1, just update code to arrParent.Values(1)

Comment: I'm not able to use **arrParent.Values(0)**,**arrParent.Values(1)**, etc etc if it has more than one item in the array... It just keeps repeating the same values after it reaches Values(10)